# Задать определенные права для роли | Discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Нашел способ как изменять роль и давать ей права, но в документации не сказано как можно дать право `"Показывать участников с ролью отдельно от в сети"` и `"Позволить всем @упоминать эту роль"`.
Задавал роли права вот так:

```
await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Гл.Админ", colour=discord.Colour(0xff0000))
adm = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "Гл.Админ")
perms = discord.Permissions(deafen_members = True) #deafen_members = True для примера                                                                            
await adm.edit(permissions = perms)
```

Comment: Так как в самом discord они отдельно и они идут как настройки а не права, то я думаю что их задать таким способом нельзя, только через сам discord.

Comment: @xZartsust но xenon бот полностю копирует сервер и копирует права для ролей, и все настройки сохраняються

Comment: Он на чем написан?

Comment: Смотрите, нашел его код может что то здесь [найдете](https://github.com/Xenon-Bot)

Comment: Скорее всего, это не предоставлено библиотекой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adm = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "Гл.Админ")
# hoist - показывает участников отдельно 
# mentionable - позволяет упоминать данную роль
await adm.edit(hoist=True, mentionable=True)
```

Прочитать про класс **Role**, можно [тут](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role).